# I would prefer + (to infinitive) + rather than + (bare infinitive) or (to infinitive)?

Tags: infinitives, would

I've found this during my studies:

> I would prefer to die in a car crash rather than **to die** in my sleep.

Is this correct? Shouldn't it be:

> I would prefer to die in a car crash rather than **die** in my sleep.

I thought you should use *bare infinitive* after *rather than* (in this type of sentences). Also, can I shorten the second sentence to:

> I would prefer to die in a car crash rather than in my sleep.

...because it's the same verb (**die**)?

Comment: There is no "should" involved; in a parallel construction like this, the _to_ infinitive marker is deletable at will by speaker's choice, depending on how they want it to sound. Rhythm controls a lot of optional deletion choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All 3 sentences make sense and are grammatical. It solely depends on style and effect intended. The repetition of the infinitive phrase 'to die'; for example may have emphasis effects.

> I would prefer **to die** in a car crash rather than **to die** in my sleep.

There is no reason not to use 2 infinitives in a sentence or that a bare infinitive has to follow an infinitive. It's just a bit formal. Also in this case they are just auxilarily verbs "helping" the lexical (main) verb.

Take for example (found from *https://www.ef.co.uk/english-resources/english-grammar/infinitive/*):

> I decided not **to** go **to** London.

(Sometimes, it is just a necessary verb. Without rewording the above, it can't be cut down any more. Another choice could be, *I decided not to visit London*)

Or as a famous quote from Shakespeare:

> **To be** or not **to be**

If you wanted to cut down on words, these are fine too:

> I would prefer to die in a car crash rather than [<s>**to**</s>] die in my sleep.
>
> I would prefer to die in a car crash rather than [<s>**to**</s>] [<s>**die**</s>] in my sleep.

Both of these examples are verb-phrase ellipsis, particularly in the second one. Verb-phrase ellipsis is commonly used in everyday English; albeit more informal and is used to avoid repetition or other style/aesthetic considerations.

Other examples:

> John can play the guitar; Mary can <s>**play the guitar**</s>, too.
>
> He has done it before, which means he will <s>**do**</s> <s>**it**</s> again.
>
> The man who wanted to order the salmon did <s>**order the
> salmon**.</s>

However, as you can see even if the above words weren't omitted, the sentences would still be grammatically correct.

Comment: Wow! I thought some things are fixed in grammar. In my school book and everywhere on the Internet it says that there's only one option possible. For example: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/common-verbs/prefer

I can see that I still have a lot to learn though. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Hey! In the link you gave it says: *When we want to say that we would like to do one thing more than another, we **can** introduce the second thing with rather than, followed by an infinitive without to:* I’d prefer to go skiing this year rather than go on a beach holiday. (go in the latter, being the bare infinitive). **Can doesn't mean should**. Wish you luck with your studies. ^^

Comment: Ha, I guess you're right! :D

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, the "to" in the second clause should act more as a preposition and not a link to the infinitive.  The gerund goes after all prepositions.  Therefore:
I would prefer to die in a car crash (rather) than to dying in my sleep.  However, this sentence is bad because it´s not parallel-- (... to die... to dying).  Hence, I would always make the first clause as the gerund as well:  I would prefer dying in a car crash (rather) than to dying in my sleep.